# Reports of in-app purchases not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

Our company is receiving many reports of in-app purchases and in-app purchase restores not doing anything. Most reports mention that no action occurs within the app when the purchase completes, or when the restore button is tapped.

All of our sandbox and live app testing shows that the IAP feature is working flawlessly. Further, the vast majority of our users report no issues with the feature. Still, it's odd that such a large number of users are reporting a problem.

We recently had to rebuild our `.xcodeproj` file from scratch, after losing the prior copy, but all of the other files remained unchanged. Could this have somehow caused the problem?

Per the debug information provided with our reports, the issue appears to affect nearly every device and every iOS version. The only common thread is that it's affecting the versions of our app produced after we rebuilt the Xcode project file.

This is more of a high-level question to see if others are facing or have faced this issue. Because of this, and because the code appears to working fine, no code has been provided, but please let me know if specific code examples would be useful.

*Per comment below, here is some relevant code relating to the restore process:*

```
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSString *product_identifier = transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    if(product_identifier == nil)
        product_identifier = @"PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER";
    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:product_identifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

Comment: The in-app purchase code should work, and there is a change on app restored portion from iOS 9.0. Can you post some source how do you call your purchase and restored method ?

Comment: @jamshed- I added code above. However, the code works without error during both sandbox and live testing, plus the issue has been reported by people using every iOS version from 7-10.

Comment: ok. see the answer. Hope it help you. I have done it for my client recently.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on App purchase restoring from iOS 9.0. 
Use this bunch of code for restoring.

```
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:[yourclass sharedHelper]]; // Yourclass can be self, or can be where did you initialise your helper. 
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate this, I'll try it out soon. It may be a while before I can report whether this worked or not, since I'll need to push out an update and wait for user feedback.

Comment: ok. Do a sandbox test. If you get it successful, it should be all right for live app. let me know you have done it successfully.

Comment: Part of the problem is that it already works just fine in both sandbox mode and in live testing. It also works just fine for the vast majority of our users. There's just a small sub-segment with seemingly no common thread who are experiencing issues.